# purrr map / lapply / sapply across groups of multiple (n > 1) elements at a time?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Suppose we have a vector, we can easily enough `lapply`, `sapply` or `map` across 1 element at a time.

Is there a way to do the same across *groups* of (>1) elements of the vector?

#### Example

Suppose we are constructing API calls by appending comma-separated `user_identifier`s to the URL, like so:

```
user_identifiers <- c("0011399", "0011400", "0013581", "0013769", "0013770", "0018374", 
  "0018376", "0018400", "0018401", "0018410", "0018415", "0018417", 
  "0018419", "0018774", "0018775", "0018776", "0018777", "0018778", 
  "0018779", "0021627", "0023492", "0023508", "0023511", "0023512", 
  "0024120", "0025672", "0025673", "0025675", "0025676", "0028226", 
  "0028227", "0028266", "0028509", "0028510", "0028512", "0028515", 
  "0028518", "0028520", "0028523", "0029160", "0033141", "0034586", 
  "0035035", "0035310", "0035835", "0035841", "0035862", "0036503", 
  "0036580", "0036583", "0036587", "0037577", "0038582", "0038583", 
  "0038587", "0039727", "0039729", "0039731", "0044703", "0044726"
)

get_data <- function(user_identifier) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.myapi.com?userIdentifier=", 
                paste0(user_identifier, collapse=","))
  fromJSON(url)
}
```

In the above, `get_data(user_identifiers)` *would* return the APIs response for all 60 `user_identifier`s in one single request.

But suppose the API accepts a maximum of 10 identifiers at a time (so we cannot do all 60 at once).

A simple solution could be to simply `map`/`lapply`/`sapply` over each element, e.g. `sapply(get_data, user_identifiers` - this would work fine - however, we would make 60 API calls, when all we really need is 6. If we could `map`/`lapply`/`sapply` over groups of 10 at a time; that would be ideal

#### Question

Is there an elegant way to `map`/`lapply`/`sapply` over *groups* of n elements at a time (where n>1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` `user_identifiers` in groups of 10 and use `sapply`/`map`/`lapply`

```
sapply(split(user_identifiers, gl(length(user_identifiers)/10, 10)), get_data)
```

where `gl` creates groups from 1 to 6 each of length 10.

```
gl(length(user_identifiers)/10, 10)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
#     4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The same groups can be created with `rep`

```
rep(1:ceiling(length(user_identifiers)/10), each = 10)
```

As @thelatemail mentioned, we can use `cut` and specify number of groups to cut the data into

```
sapply(split(user_identifiers, cut(seq_along(user_identifiers),6)), get_data)
```

Comment: Also `cut` - `cut(seq_along(user_identifiers),10)` for cutting into *n* groups.